# Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getElementsByTagName()

Tags: php, parsing

I would like to parse an html table using PHP's DOMDocument, so I use a foreach for every table:   foreach($_POST['comparison'] as $value) {   } in which  i nested the code below. So from the comparison table i want to take each row ($value), the value contains an html table (`<table> ...</table>`). Here is the table i want to parse:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td >.....</td>
            <td>....</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>....</td>
            <td>.....</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The second code goes like this, i create a foreach for the rows, then an index ($i) for every row and inside every row another foreach with a new index ($j) for the columns, so the purpose is to echo each column of every row like this (first column-first row, second column-first row, first column-second row, second column-second row...

```
          foreach($_POST['comparison'] as $value) {


    echo  "<div id='primary' class='content-area'>";

               var_dump($value);  // check the type in the variable value 
      $dom = new DOMDocument;

    $dom->loadHTML($value);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');


     foreach ($tables->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $element1) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $element1->length; $i++) {

             echo   $element1->item($i)->nodeValue . "\n";

               foreach ($element1->getElementsByTagName('td') as $element2) {

                  for ($j = 0; $j < $element2->length; $j++) {

               echo $element2->item($j)->nodeValue . "\n";  }

           /* $value_spec[] = $element2->nodeValue + "<br>";  */
        }
     }
  }

    echo " </div><!-- content-area -->";              

 }

}
```

I followed the instructions for the error "Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getElementsByTagName()", which is to add item() to have access to every cell of the table but the error remains. I would appreciate if someone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php

$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($value);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
$tr = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr'); 

foreach ($tr as $element1) {        
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($element1); $i++) {
        echo $element1->nodeValue . "\n";
        foreach ($element1->getElementsByTagName('td') as $element2) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($element2); $j++) {
                echo $element2->nodeValue . "\n";  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the comment, the error is gone but now it just prints a number of lines: string(5) "Array" according to how many checkboxes I have checked..

Comment: it appears a new error "Array to string conversion", but thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
    $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName ('table');

// At this point, if you are sure that you want the first table found,  add
$table = $tables->item(0);
// Below working code, I don't undersatand what you do with that loops
     foreach ($table->getElementsByTagName ('tr') as $tr) {
          foreach ($tr->getElementsByTagName ('td') as $td) {
                 echo $td->nodeValue . "\n";  
         }
     }
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/902208)

Comment: @SokratisV On lever `tr` it's nothing to echo. Save it only on level `td`

Comment: glad to help. Good luck!